# How can I ask for a question to be moved to Unix/Linux?

Tags: support

A while back I asked [Why doesn't tty7 show a prompt with no display manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291819/why-doesnt-tty7-show-a-prompt-with-no-display-manager). It didn't really get answered, which is OK, because it's just theoretical and not very pressing.

That said, having used Stack Exchange for a while since I asked, I'd like to ask for the question to be moved to Unix & Linux. How can I do this? Should I just delete and re-ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically speaking, either.

You're free to flag it and we can migrate it (at our discretion - we may disagree with your choice) or you can nuke our copy and start a new question over there.

On this question, I couldn't resist answering it, mostly because I wanted to refresh my mind on how and why things are laid out the way they are. I didn't find many reasons "why" but I did find out "how".

There is scope for a "Why are there six text ttys with X on tty7 in most distributions?" question and Unix.SE would be a fairly good place for that.